# Are there rules for playing as a child?

Tags: star-wars-d6

I'm thinking of making a character akin to Anakin from episode 1: a slave child who's really good with the Force (although I'm not a pod racer or the Chosen One, or annoying).

Are there rules for playing as children?

I'd like to follow official rules if at all possible, before I go to my GM and try and work out rules with them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mdrichey: Unfortunately, because edits within the window of a few minutes (I'm not sure of the exact period - 5 minutes?) don't show up separately in the revision history, I don't think you can "undo" it except by making those changes manually again.

Answer (score 6):

The rulebook contains a template for creating a kid character, at the end of the book. I've just checked and every version has the template, adapted for the current set of rules, and with pictures of varying quality.

The rules are the same whatever template you chose, or even if you chose to create your character without following any template. The only difference is that the Kid has a reduced move, 8 instead of the usual 10.